# [ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: NoSectionError: No section: 'ceph'

Tags: ceph

Follow the official docs:http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-start-preflight/#rhel-centos

I do the below configuration of the `ceph.repo`:

```
[ceph-noarch]
name=Ceph noarch packages
baseurl=http://download.ceph.com/rpm-jewel/el7/noarch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
type=rpm-md
gpgkey=https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
```

But when I use ceph-deploy to install the ceph, I will get the error:

> [ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: NoSectionError: No section: 'ceph'

In I change the configuration of the `[ceph-noarch]` to `[ceph]`, I will get the below information:

> [ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: NoSectionError: No section: 'ceph-noarch'

How to do with it?

Comment: `NoSectionError` certainly sounds like the respective `configparser` exception class. Having only superficial experience with `yum` I reckon that you'd have to have at least two separate section. One for your specific architecture and one for architecture-agnostic packages. Likely the difference will simply be in the `baseurl` value.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was caused by having admin-node and the node as the same machine, `ceph-deploy install` will try to install new `ceph.repo` but it will found another one already exists.

I simply overwrite the old file:

```
sudo mv /etc/yum.repos.d/ceph.repo.rpmnew /etc/yum.repos.d/ceph.repo
```